# How to create a POST request in my case?

Tags: angularjs, http, service

I am trying to make a `POST` request via `$resource` object in Angular.

I have something like

```
(function (angular) {
    angular.module('myApp')
        .factory('myService', [
           '$resource',
            function ($resource) {
                var serviceObj = $resource('http://testProject/products/',   {id: '@id'},{
                    'createItem' : {
                        url: 'http://testProject/item/:id',
                        method: 'POST',
                        params: {type: ‘@type'}
                    }
                });
                return serviceObj;
            }
        ]);
})(angular);
```

in my controller

```
 //omit the controller codes…

 myService.type = ‘Detail’;   
 myService.createItem(function(data) {
       console.log(data)
 });
```

I see stuff back from the `console.log` but it has the wrong data because the type is shown as ‘`Name`’ instead of ‘`Detail`’. I know api supports that and I don’t see anything wrong with my service. Can someone help me out for it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are getting data back,

I would try:

```
           console.log(data.data);
```

Since your are returning an object from your service.